# How to remove a context manager from an ExitStack

Tags: python, stack, with-statement

I have a long-running process called an Updater, that has updates (to an ETL system) submitted to it. The updates have resource requirements that are managed by adding a context manager to the Updater's ExitStack. Some updates will include new configuration, which means that effected resources must be released from the stack and a newly configured version of the resource will be added. I need something like:

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    ctx_manager = open("file.txt")
    f = stack.enter_context(ctx_manager)
    ...
    ctx_pop(ctx_manager, stack)  # remove the given context manager from the stack
```

Below is an example of something I've gotten to work, but it relies on accessing protected members. I was hoping there might be a less 'dirty' solution than this:

```
def ctx_pop(cm, stack):
    for item in stack._exit_callbacks:
        if item.__self__ is cm:
            break
    else:
        raise KeyError(repr(cm))
    stack._exit_callbacks.remove(item)
    item(None, None, None)
```

Edit: Added known solution

Comment: Looking at the source code `ExitStack` uses a `deque` to store wrappers for the contexts `.__exit__` method so you would need to be able to identify the wrapper by the original context manager which, as far as I know, isn't possible.  You may need to reinvent (at least partially) the functionality of `ExitStack` to be able to remove contexts ahead of time.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thank you. I discovered the same thing inspecting `ExitStack` objects in a Jupyter Notebook. They have a deque of closures who's `__self__` attribute is a context manager. I'll put some code up as an known solution, but I was hoping for a less 'hack' solution. I wanted to see if there was a cleaner solution before I submit to Python Ideas or add it myself (which I've never done before).

Answer (score 3):

You have to extend `ExitStack` with your own `pop`-method:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from collections import deque

class ExitStackWithPop(ExitStack):
    def pop(self, cm):
        callbacks = self._exit_callbacks
        self._exit_callbacks = deque()
        found = None
        while callbacks:
            cb = callbacks.popleft()
            if cb.__self__ == cm:
                found = cb
            else:
                self._exit_callbacks.append(cb)
        if not found:
            raise KeyError("context manager not found")
        found(None, None, None)
```

Comment: it is not `_ExitStack__self__` it is just `__self__`, attributes with two trailing underscores are not private (just think of all the magic method names)  Also you don't need to recreate the `deque`, you can just iterate through the items and `.remove` the one that has `.__self__ == cm`

Comment: Thanks! That's very close to the solution I'm using right now, but I like the idea of subclassing. It seem cleaner that way.

Comment: Bleh. You're reaching into the implementation details here.

Comment: Since [this changes](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4790/files#diff-e00601a380ba6c916ba4333277fe6ea43d2477804002ab1ae64480f80fec8e3aR447) at [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) it must be `if cb[1].__self__ == cm:` to work. (Anyway its a very low level dependency to contextlib)

Comment: it is odd that this functionality is not included in ExitStack. It really should. 
Clearly there are use-cases where one needs to manage objects dynamically. Have you considered submitting an enhacement request?

Comment: I just submitted an enhancement request https://bugs.python.org/issue45184

Answer (score 1):

`contextlib.ExitStack` only supports exiting all context managers at once. You can't pop context managers individually. If you want to do this, you should keep track of your context managers with something other than an ExitStack.

Comment: Reimplementing the functionality similar to `contextlib.ExitStack` (keeping track of context managers) is certainly not easy.